# Java recursive generics class wildcard matching

Tags: java, generics

Having these generic interface and class:

```
interface TestIntf<T extends TestIntf<T>> 
{
    void test(T param);
}

class TestImpl<T extends TestIntf<T>> implements TestIntf<T> 
{
    @Override
    public void test(T param) { System.out.println(param); }
}
```

This fails:

```
Class<? extends TestIntf<?>> clz = TestImpl.class;
```

(Type mismatch: cannot convert from `Class<TestImpl>` to `Class<? extends TestIntf<?>>`)

Why? How to properly provide a reference to `TestImpl` class to match `Class<? extends TestIntf<?>>`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't. Use an unsafe cast.

```
Class<? extends TestIntf<?>> clz = (Class<? extends TestIntf<?>>) TestImpl.class;
```

or don't use the inner generics:

```
Class<? extends TestIntf> clz = TestImpl.class;
```

**Update:** When it regards annotations, there is nothing you can do - the annotation has to be changed. You cannot have a class literal represent a generic type.

Comment: what to do if the class reference is required in annotation? compiler complies on typecast there.